# Spanish abbreviations of days of the week

Tags: abreviaturas, tiempo

In English, the days of the week have single-letter abbreviations (M, T, W, etc.) and three-letter abbreviations (Mon., Tue., Wed.). What are the standard ways to abbreviate the days of the week in Spanish?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know if there's any official standard about this, but:

The single-letter abbreviations are:

> L, M, X, J, V, S, D

Note that *miércoles* is usually written as X, so as not to confuse it with *martes*.

Regarding múltiple letter abbreviations, the usual way is two-letter abbreviations:

> Lu, Ma, Mi, Ju, Vi, Sa, Do

**UPDATE:**

[A reference](http://www.manualdeestilo.com/escribir/abreviaturas-de-los-meses-y-los-dias-de-la-semana/)

Comment: I've seen the single-letter abbreviations, and the straightforward three-letter abbreviations, but never the two-letter ones you mention.

Comment: On the contrary, the two-letters forms is the most used in my experience (Argentina).

Comment: Windows 10 for Culture Spanish Spain (es-ES) uses the single letter abbreviations LM X J V S D

Comment: It appears the reference link, manualdeestilo.com has been down a while.  Asking google to search within the website for abreviaturas returns zero results.  Does anyone have a reference?
Also, in general please share authoritative style references for Latin American Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

In Costa Rica and Puerto Rico martes is [abbreviated with a K](https://www.scribd.com/doc/129057267/Itinerarios-Buses-CR) for the same reason:

- L, K, M, J, V, S, D